# Real Analysis: Determine $|J|$ where $J=J_1 \cup J_2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $J_1= \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ and $J_2=\{-2,-\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 2\}$ be partitions of $[2,2]$.

Let $J = J_1 \cup J_2$.

Determine $|J| = (max_i (x_i - x_{i-1})$.

Would the answer be $1$ as the $2-1=1$ is the max. difference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct, assuming that $x_i$ means the elements of the set in increasing order.